# Dealing with spaces in linq to xml

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file that is like this:

```
<xml>I need this text<notthistext>blahblah<notthistext></xml>
```

I get the text by doing something like this:

```
var mycollection = from myNode in myDoc.descendents("xml") select new { test = Convert.ToString(myNode.Nodes().First())}
```

but the problem is that there are carrige returns and spaces that don't exist in the file

this is what i get:

```
"/r/n      I need this text"
```

What is going on!!!!!
What i need is:

```
"I need this text"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered [Trim, specifying the characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx)?

Comment: I did but I think something has to be really wrong here.  why are the spaces and carriage return being added in in the first place?

Comment: "the problem is that there are carrige returns and spaces that don't exist in the file"

Are you 100% sure?  What does the file look like in Notepad or TextPad?